# "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required" when exporting PDF from SSRS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am trying to render an image in PDF report using Report viewer but Export button not working.

Below is the exception details:

```
Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: value
```

Many Posts suggested that issue was in Sql server 2005 version and has been resolved in CU7.
But currently i am using SQL Server 2008R2 version and getting this issue.

Comment: OQ was changed by author after it fixed the OQ.

Answer (score 3):

SSRS has issues with high resolution files and certain formats. Since your post states the image comes from a CyberShot camera and the original uncompressed file from the camera is used see below. **Always use 72dpi or lower on images in SSRS.**

PNG's and JPEG's with a high resolution **will not export** yet appear in the report viewer. Change the resolution and size of the image itself to something low (200x200, **72dpi**) using an image editor such as Paint.NET. A lower image size scaled up to your need within the report seems to do the trick.

You can also try other formats. Make sure to update your link within the report to the new image or save to the database depending on how you store your images. If the downloaded image appears then you can try cranking the image size up.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I think issue is not due to dpi or size because i have some picture having (640 x 480, 350dpi) attributes but they are rendering properly and there is no issue in exporting PDF.
i think issue is related to meta data on which i am working now.

Comment: I've used something similar to this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb1fe0f7-a230-40af-9d56-3d166abed6b7/how-do-i-view-and-edit-metadata) in the past in an SSIS Script Task to import directly to a database table in conjuction with a BitmapImage object and run of the mill Scale algorithms to do all my conversion (in my case TIFF to PNG, scale it down at 72dpi). That's how I came across an issue like yours.

Comment: I am getting below exception while try to export image in pdf

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: value]
   System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Position(Int64 value) +10437656
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.CanvasPDF.MonochromeJpeg(MemoryStream memStream) +347
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.CanvasPDF.ProcessImage(CanvasImagePDF image, Double left, Double top, Double width, Double height, Boolean scaleImage) +1270

Comment: This is a completely different question and should be posted as such according to Stack's guidelines.